# Does jQuery automatically remove attached even handlers from objects when I remove them?

Tags: jquery, dom, event-handling, dom-manipulation

Well my interest is whether jQuery does remove attached event handlers from the DOM object and all it's descendants (if they got some event handlers attached as well), if I just remove that DOM object with `jQuery('.selector').remove()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/remove#expr):
"Note that this function starting with 1.2.2 will also remove all event handlers and internally cached data."